# equivalent SWTTreeNode API

Tags: java, swing, swt, jface

Please let me know if there is any equivalent SWT Tree API for below mentioned Swing API

```
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
```

Comment: Did you do any research yourself?

Comment: yes i did ... in SWT/Jface we have ITreeContentProvider. But i am not sure if itz the same comapred to swing.

Comment: I am looking something same as below link which is been developed using swing http://knowledgeshare.awardspace.info/?p=137

Comment: Checkout the [Tree widget here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/)

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent to them is [`TreeNodeContentProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeNodeContentProvider.html) and [`TreeNode`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeNode.html) respectively, but I'd implementing your own content provider instead (just as I'd suggest implementing `TreeModel` in Swing).

Answer (score 0):

I embedded swt-swing to populate tree value from DB and solution is wrkng now.

```
                      Composite composite_tree = new Composite(unitPriceChngeComposite12, SWT.EMBEDDED);
                      composite_tree.setBounds(20, 207, 230, 398);

                      Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite_tree);

                      Panel panel = new Panel();
                      frame.add(panel);
                      panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

                      JRootPane rootPane = new JRootPane();
                      panel.add(rootPane);

                      tree_unitPrice = new JTree();
                      rootPane.getContentPane().add(tree_unitPrice, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```